# Text Widget Automatically Adding Website Link

Tags: widgets, widget-text

I am working on [this website](http://www.psychologyresource.ca/) and the "Useful Links" section at the bottom (second footer widget area) is not working because somehow the current page links got added to the links (please hover on the links and see the bottom left on your browser to see what I mean).

I check the widget and the links should work, here are some of the code inside the text widget

```
<a href="www.ordre.psy.qc.ca/en/" rel="nofollow">www.ordre.psy.qc.ca/en/</a>
<a href="www.cpa.ca" rel="nofollow">www.cpa.ca</a>
<a href="www.nimh.nih.gov/index.shtml" rel="nofollow">www.nimh.nih.gov/index.shtml</a>
```

Can anyone tell me what is happening? Currently I am checking the JS files to see if the links are added by Javascript.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: See: http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/q/88167/21376

Comment: Thanks s_ha_dum. Resolved the issue and great explanation! Hmm.. so how do I close this? LOL.. well, problem solved!

Comment: Feel free to upvote helpful answers.

Comment: I would.. tried to upvote yours on the link but I couldn't (need 15 - two more - reps). Can't do anything here since you leave your answer as comment. I certainly owe and remember you though, you've helped me before :)