# How to redirect homepage to actual URL?

Tags: images, redirect, urls

I have a stupid problem. In the custom header template I include on all pages are some images. When I set the links to the images as images/image.png it works on the homepage but not on other pages. When I set the links to these images as **../** images/image.png it works on all other pages but not on the homepage..

This is because the homepage url is given as 'mysite.com' instead of 'mysite.com/home/'.

Is there any easy solution to this problem?

My guess was to redirect any visit to the homepage to 'mysite.com/home/'. But it looks like Wordpress itself prevents this. If I type 'mysite.com/home/' in an adress bar it redirects immediately to 'mysite.com'.

I had no idea that changing these image links would give me such a weird problem :) I hope anyone here has a solution for it. Thx in advance!

Comment: See: http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/a/88193/21376

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Don't use relative paths in WordPress, put the images in your theme directory and use the API to output correct paths.

```
<img src="<?php echo get_template_directory_uri(); ?>/images/image.jpg">
```

Comment: +1, but that needs to be `get_template_directory_uri()`, not `get_stylesheet_directory_uri()`.

Comment: @ChipBennett depends on the context, `get_stylesheet_directory_uri` will work for child themes. a common issue here is people using `get_template_directory_uri` and wondering why it's not loading assets from their child theme.

Comment: A Child Theme is the *only* context in which `get_stylesheet_directory_uri()` should be used. I see quite a bit more confusion in Child Themes when the parent (template) mis-referenced the stylesheet directory, instead of the template directory.

Comment: Actually, I am using child themes :) So thank you all for providing both of these functions!