# WordPress plugin add_filter returning a link does not work. What is the correct way?

Tags: plugins, filters

```
function ls_de_options($content) {
            return '<h3><a href="www.google.com">Hello World</a></h3>'.$content;

        }
add_filter( 'the_content', 'ls_de_options' );
```

The link does not work. It is taking me to http://example.com/www.google.com

What I wanted to do was to put a share button link to every post in my blog
Or is there a better way to add share button.

Comment: See: http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/a/88193/21376

Answer (score 1):

The reason the link isn't working is because you haven't formatted it correctly.

This:

```
return '<h3><a href="www.google.com">Hello World</a></h3>'.$content;
```

Should be this:

```
return '<h3><a href="https://www.google.com/">Hello World</a></h3>'.$content;
```

To answer your other question: There are a lot of social sharing plugins that will add sharing links to your content.

Comment: Not best practice to print links in WordPress using your method James and Puni.

Comment: Brad whats your suggestion